I am unable to correctly upload files en.stm32cubeg4-v1-5-2.zip and en.stm32cubeg4-v1-6-0.zip to the STM32CubeMX repository
I am unable to correctly upload files en.stm32cubeg4-v1-5-2.zip and en.stm32cubeg4-v1-6-0.zip  to the STM32CubeMX repository in local mode. These files were downloaded from the website ST.com and are the package and patch for Nucleo-STM32G4xx evaluation boards.
By simply unpacking these files into a folder ...\STM32Cube\Repository CubeMX does not see them. When trying to install these files from the CubeMX "Home" tab by clicking "Install/Remove" -> "From local" -> "Open" -> "Install", the following message appears, the same for both files (see image):

I searched for a solution on the Internet, but found only tips to do what I already did: put archive files in a separate folder and specify the path for local installation of CubeMX (ver.6.10).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
